# Get checkbox values with different class name in the same div id - jquery mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the values of checkboxes which are in the same divid but have different class name.

```
      <tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center">
       
        <div id="divEntities" style="width:100%;height:150px;overflow-y:scroll;align:center;">
            <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="95%" align="center" border="1">
             
                @{
                    var i = 0;
                    while (i < Model.CompanyMaster.Count)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:50%" hidden="hidden"><input type="checkbox" class="EntityCheck" id="chkCompanyId" /> @Model.CompanyMaster[i].COMPANYID</td>
                            @if ((i + 1) < Model.CompanyMaster.Count)
                            {
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="EntityCheck" /> @Model.CompanyMaster[i + 1].COMPANY_NAME</td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="CurrentYear" /> @DateTime.Now.Year </td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="PreviousYear" /> @DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year </td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="LastYear" /> @DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year </td>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <td></td>
                            }
                        </tr>
                        i = i + 1;
                    }
                }
            </table>
        </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
```

With above code, I am able to populate data in a table with multiple checkboxes, but unable to get the value of the checkbox where the class name is something other than EntityCheck. Below is my jQuery function:

```
function GetSelectedEntities() {
var entities = "";
$("#divEntities").find('td').each(function (i, el) {

    var checkbox = $(this).find('input.EntityCheck');

    //var check1 = $(this).find('CurrentYear');
    //var check2 = $(this).find('PreviousYear');
    //var check3 = $(this).find('LastYear');

    var check1 = $('.CurrentYear').val();
    var check2 = $('.PreviousYear').val();
    var check3 = $('.LastYear').val();
           

    if (checkbox != undefined && $(checkbox).length > 0 && $(checkbox).prop('checked') == true) {
        var EntityData = jQuery.trim($(this).text());

        if (entities == "") {
            entities = EntityData;
        }
        else {
            entities = entities + "|" + EntityData;
        }
    }
});
return entities;
```

}

jQuery function is invoked on a button click event:

```
 <button style="font:normal 9pt Arial;height:30px;width:100px;border-radius:5px; border:none; background-color:royalblue; color:white" id="btnAdd" onclick="GetSelectedEntities(event);">
                    Add
                </button>
```

I tried by giving the same class name to all the checkboxes but the problem was that I was able to get the values of the year checkbox, even if the CompanyName was not selected. I need the year values only if the CompanyName checkbox is checked and it's corresponding years. I also tried by giving the id='' to the year checkbox, but could not get the values.

I am unable to figure where I am going wrong. What is that I need to change in my jQuery to get the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
$('#btnAdd').on('click', function(){
    var checked = $('table').find('input:checked');
    checked.each(function(){
        alert($(this).closest('td').text());
        //do your stuff here..
    });
});
```

Se working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c8n4rLjy/

Answer (score 0):

I had to make changes to get the desired solution. Please find the solution below:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center">
       
        <div id="divEntities" style="width:100%;height:150px;overflow-y:scroll;align:center;">
            <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="95%" align="center" border="1">
             
                @{
                    var i = 0;
                    while (i < Model.CompanyMaster.Count)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:50%" hidden="hidden"><input type="checkbox" class="EntityCheck" id="chkCompanyId" /> @Model.CompanyMaster[i].COMPANYID</td>
                            @if ((i + 1) < Model.CompanyMaster.Count)
                            {
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="EntityCheck" /> @Model.CompanyMaster[i + 1].COMPANY_NAME</td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkYear" /> @DateTime.Now.Year </td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkYear" /> @DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year </td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkYear" /> @DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).Year </td>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <td></td>
                            }
                        </tr>
                        i = i + 1;
                    }
                }
            </table>
        </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
```

jQuery:

```
function GetSelectedEntities() {

    var entities = "";
    var CompanySelected = false;
    var counter = 0;
    $("#divEntities").find('td').each(function (i, el) {
        counter = counter + 1  

        var checkbox = $(this).find('input.EntityCheck');

        var checkboxyear = $(this).find('input.chkYear');
        if (counter == 2) {
            if (checkbox != undefined) {
                if ($(checkbox).prop('checked') == true) {
                    CompanySelected = true;
                    var EntityData = jQuery.trim($(this).text());

                    if (entities == "") {
                        entities = EntityData;
                    }
                    else {
                        entities = entities + "-" + EntityData;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    CompanySelected = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (counter > 2) {
            if (CompanySelected == true) {

                if (checkboxyear != undefined) {
                    if ($(checkboxyear).prop('checked') == true) {
                        var EntityData = jQuery.trim($(this).text());
                        entities = entities + "|" + EntityData;
                       
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(counter == 5)
        {
            counter = 0;
        }
    });
    return entities;
}
```